# Retrieve console output to redirect into a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve whatever is output to the Python shell so that I can then redirect it into a GUI.

All I need is a way to get the latest shell output, similar to the `.get()` command for Tkinter.